# What is the correct calculation to span some columns?

Tags: lengths

I want to create a column spanning 5 columns with `m` column specifier. It seems my calculation `\multicolumn{5}{m{5\temp}|}{\hrulefill}` is wrong as the rule does not occupy the left space. What is the correct calculation?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=3mm,bottom=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\tabcolsep=1mm\relax
\arrayrulewidth=1pt\relax
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\newlength\temp
\temp=\dimexpr\dimexpr\textwidth-7\arrayrulewidth-12\tabcolsep\relax/6\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*{6}{m{\temp}|}}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\LaTeX &\multicolumn{5}{m{5\temp}|}{\hrulefill}\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No calculation necessary:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=3mm,bottom=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\tabcolsep=1mm\relax
\arrayrulewidth=1pt\relax
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\newlength\temp
\temp=\dimexpr\dimexpr\textwidth-7\arrayrulewidth-12\tabcolsep\relax/6\relax

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{6}{m{\temp}|}}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\LaTeX &\multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}|}{\hrulefill}\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the table you're creating, no (human) calculations of any kind are required: Just (a) employ a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment and (b) the `c` column type for the cell that spans multiple columns of type `X`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,hmargin=3mm,top=3mm,bottom=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % use "m" rather than "p" raw column type

\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}         % default value: 6pt=2.11mm
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}  % default value: 0.4pt
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{6}{X|}} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
\LaTeX &\multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}|}{\hrulefill}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
\multicolumn{5}{m{\dimexpr\textwidth-\temp-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\hrulefill}
```